# Django orm query help

Tags: django, django-models

Employee class has id, first_name, last_name, and a lot more fields.

I want to select all the employees that do not have the same last_name, It's something like distinct in SQL, how to do that?

`employees = Employee.objects.value('last_name').distinct()` will only include the last_name, so I cannot find id.

If I do `employees = Employee.objects.value('id', 'last_name').distinct()` the `results.count()` looks different.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to select only those employees which have unique last_name?

Comment: yeah if there are two people with the same last name, which ID do you want? or did you want to exclude any people that share a last_name with someone else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just because you may have employees with the same last name.
When you add 'id' in the query, you ask for all distincts rows based on the two criterias, and you always have distinct id.
Am I clear ?...